# Passing Empty string parameter in URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, url

I want to pass an empty string parameter in a url. I don't know how to do it.

I am passing these parameters in the url for a grid. In the database if I using Race=''. I get the respective records. I need to pass this in the url

```
test.aspx?race=""
```

Answer (score 12):

The url would look like this:

```
text.aspx?race=
```

or

```
text.aspx?race=&otherParam=value&etc=otherValue
```

Then you would have code to handle race being empty:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["race"]))
// handle the empty race differently
```

Comment: Modsecurity will not like this.  It wants to see something between = and &, or it will flag it as an attack attempt.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass an empty string in url like this

```
test.aspx?race=%02%03
```

%02 - start of text ASCII Character

%03 - end of text ASCII Character

In [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) page you can find other characters too.

Comment: Interesting. However, AFAIK, URL spec does not define any special behavior for those two characters. Your linked page says **"Control characters have nothing to do inside a URL."** Given that, I see only two possibities: a) those characters are discarded from the value, in which case this is "overkill"; why not just use earlier answer `test.aspx?race=`? OR b) those characters are included w/i the value, in which case you would need special logic to look for that string of two characters - seems undesireable. I have not tested, but I believe "(b)" is what happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim race As String

race = ""

Response.Redirect("page.aspx?race=" & race)
```

Is this what you want??

Comment: I am trying to pull out records from the data base where the field race is blank (Select * from tbltest where race=''). I want to know how will I pass the balnk parameter in a query.string or URL to a grid

Comment: It kind of does answer the question, though it's a bit vague about it - the correct answer is that the URL should be `text.aspx?race=`.